# How To: Reset scrollbar position inside of a divide with scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

So here is the situation...

I am using jQuery/AJAX to call various HTML sequences into my main controlpanel/webpage.

Some requests return a very long result, and require a scrollbar to be shown within the popup divide.

When the customer closes that initial long result and opens another lengthy result... the popup divide will show the exact same "distance from the top of the divide" as it did for when we previously closed the divide.

In essence, the browser (firefox 9.0) is saving the location of the divide's scrollbar and replacing it when I call another bunch of html into the same divide via AJAX.

How to stop this "convenience"???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this before loading new data:

```
$('#yourDIV').scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: That solution seems like it should work but it doesn't apparently.

Comment: Let this be a lesson to those that work too late... don't! techfoobar is 100% correct and I was just too tired to realize it. Thank you.